# CPU at 100%, but no processes showing significant usage

Tags: activity-monitor, cpu, macos

### Situation:

All 4 cores maxed out. Mac noticeably lagging.

### Attempted Solution:

*(Reveals wildly contradictory information.)*

1. Closed all applications
2. Opened Activity Monitor
3. Totaled all Process ID activity and noticed that all processes listed (including activity monitor and finder) only add up to about 10-20% CPU usage, **BUT ALL 4 CORES ARE STILL REDLINED/MAXED OUT.**

### Additional Info:

Activity monitor also says that:

- User Usage is < 5%
- System Usage is almost steady at 85% (yet no PID's show significant CPU use)
- Idle 10%

The system in question is running OS X 10.7.5 (Lion).
*(I'm writing from another machine.)*

### Three Part Question:

1. **HOW CAN WE STOP THIS BEHAVIOR?**
2. Why is the total CPU usage drastically different from the PID list total?
3. (BONUS) Why isn't there any system PID showing up that correlates with the 85% system usage?

Comment: first try this official tool from Intel to see if the numbers are real http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-power-gadget-20

Comment: Are you looking at processes for all users?

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: This is only a partial answer, so any other info as to why this happened could be good for others with this problem.**

Literally, upon simply plugging in the power cord, all symptoms immediately stopped. (Battery was well above 10%.)

- CPU usage dropped to normal levels.
- Resulting sluggishness stopped as well.

Comment: Sounds like you somehow reset the System management Controller (SMC)

Comment: The same exact thing happened to me after re-syncing my iCloud library. CPU was at 100% but no significant processes were showing up in Activity Monitor or htop (using command-line). As soon as I pulled at the power chord, the issue immediately went away. After pulling the power chord, however, the processes photolibraryd and Photos showed up in Activity Monitor at 90+% CPU-usage, but now the actual CPU-usage is low. Very strange behaviours, indeed.

Comment: I eventually found the culprit. In my case, the Folding@Home client (fah) was running in the background when the power cable was connected. I had installed the client some months ago and forgotten about it. The CPU-usage had nothing to do with Apple Photos or iCloud.